# Scrape text of a specific pattern using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, node.js, web-scraping

I am fetching the contents of a webpage (using scipio module of nodejs). From the webpage, I need to extract all lines of the form {title: "..." ......}. The relevant portion of the webpage is shown below:

```
//<!--
if(!ALEXA)
var ALEXA={viewsHelpers:{}};
if(!ALEXA.viewsHelpers.map)
ALEXA.viewsHelpers.map={};
ALEXA.viewsHelpers.map.div= "visitsMap";
ALEXA.viewsHelpers.map.areas=[
{title:"United States: 29.8%",id:"US",value:"5.39"},
{title:"India: 8.9%",id:"IN",value:"4.19"},
{title:"Russia: 3.3%",id:"RU",value:"3.19"},
{title:"Japan: 3.3%",id:"JP",value:"3.19"},
{title:"Brazil: 3%",id:"BR",value:"3.1"},
{title:"United Kingdom: 2.9%",id:"GB",value:"3.06"},
{title:"Iran: 2.5%",id:"IR",value:"2.92"},
{title:"France: 2.3%",id:"FR",value:"2.83"},
{title:"Spain: 2.3%",id:"ES",value:"2.83"},
{title:"Germany: 2.3%",id:"DE",value:"2.83"},
{title:"Mexico: 2.1%",id:"MX",value:"2.74"},
{title:"Italy: 2%",id:"IT",value:"2.69"},
{title:"Canada: 1.9%",id:"CA",value:"2.64"},
{title:"Indonesia: 1.7%",id:"ID",value:"2.53"},
{title:"Turkey: 1.2%",id:"TR",value:"2.18"},
{title:"Australia: 1.2%",id:"AU",value:"2.18"},
{title:"Pakistan: 1%",id:"PK",value:"2"},
{title:"Taiwan: 0.9%",id:"TW",value:"1.89"},
{title:"Argentina: 0.9%",id:"AR",value:"1.89"},
{title:"Netherlands: 0.9%",id:"NL",value:"1.89"},
{title:"South Korea: 0.9%",id:"KR",value:"1.89"},
{title:"Poland: 0.9%",id:"PL",value:"1.89"},
{title:"China: 0.8%",id:"CN",value:"1.78"},
{title:"Saudi Arabia: 0.8%",id:"SA",value:"1.78"},
{title:"Malaysia: 0.8%",id:"MY",value:"1.78"},
{title:"South Africa: 0.8%",id:"ZA",value:"1.78"},
{title:"Thailand: 0.7%",id:"TH",value:"1.64"},
{title:"Nigeria: 0.7%",id:"NG",value:"1.64"},
{title:"Colombia: 0.7%",id:"CO",value:"1.64"},
{title:"Egypt: 0.6%",id:"EG",value:"1.49"},
{title:"Ukraine: 0.6%",id:"UA",value:"1.49"},
{title:"Venezuela: 0.6%",id:"VE",value:"1.49"},
{title:"Philippines: 0.6%",id:"PH",value:"1.49"},
{title:"Singapore: 0.5%",id:"SG",value:"1.31"},
{title:"Greece: 0.5%",id:"GR",value:"1.31"}];
//-->
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you can do

```
html = html.split('\n').filter(function(l){
   return !/^\s*{title:.*},?\s*/.test(l)
}).join('\n');
```

Comment: The last title as no comma after the bracket, will it fail?

Comment: @dystroy: I scrape the website data as shown below: 
scipio.get (url, function ($, body) {...}
the data is stored in $.
When I use your above code replacing html by $, I get the error: "TypeError: Object [object Function] has no method 'split'"

Comment: Or use a module like `byline` to work on your stream by lines.

Comment: @dystroy: toString appears to have worked without errors. How can I display the contents of html. console.log gives output as [Object Function]. I am on nodejs